# How to fake a volume when you can't use volume? GLB export only supports meshes

Tags: export, volumetrics, gltf

I want a cube exported to a GLB file to look like a volume. Think "smoke," not "hard-edged box."

Sadly, GLB format only supports meshes --> hard-edged boxes.

So how might I fake a volume, those nice soft edges and filled spaces? 30,000 tiny semitransparent icospheres? No.

For reference, here's an image showing the Blender screenshot (black background) with meshes/volumes (left/right). And the GLB export screenshot (white background). Notice all the cubes in the GLB export look like hard edged boxes.

[image: Screenshot of blender view on left and GLB export view on right]

In Blender I simply used the Principled BDSF output to the surface node of the Material Output for meshes and the volume node for the volumes. I tried using the volume shader also but I could not make that work either.

Note: I am only using a cube as a simple example. I want to implement this for any object. Suzanne for example.

Follow up!

So not much of a solution, not clever and very time consuming. I am now using shrink. I am reducing/enlarging my emissive object by very small amounts. Each larger size (.01 increments) has a small decrease in alpha. I use six shrunk objects.

All of that work, just to get a bit of "bloom/halo" around an emissive object. Soften up the edges. Think "candle flame" not "candle cutout." Why? Because I can't use bloom or volume when I export the object to GLB (for an AR project and possibly Sketchfab display). Ouch. Perhaps if I knew how to bake? That might work.

Better solutions from those more experienced would be helpful.

Comment: There's a section on [volume in the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html#volume),. have you tried that?

Comment: Yes. My understanding is that that volume is used with thickness in transmission for things like glass. How much darker it gets the deeper it is in the glass. It is not that clear, to me, how all that works but there are other posts which give more detail and exactly why volumes, like clouds, are not supported. Search GLB+cloud and you can also find them.

Comment: This type of volumetric rendering is not something that the current glTF specification or its extensions allow. Or any other standard formats I'm aware of, unfortunately, the volumetric technique is just not interchangeable among programs.

I imagine you could do something like this if Blender gains more support for export to node-based material formats like MaterialX or MDL, or if glTF adds similar features (support for volumetric transmission in glTF is fairly new, for example). Until then it is probably not possible.

Comment: Yes! GLB definitely is limited in this way. That is why I need a workaround to "fake a volume." 

My first thought was to use many planes with emission and various values of alpha. Or a bunch of small spheres with the same material characteristics. But that's a lot of planes and a lot of spheres. And a major difficulty to fill an object, like Suzanne with planes or spheres. If I have to, I will try to find an easy way to do it. But I'm hoping there is an easier way.